# variables with inconsistent numbers of samples, Naive bayes

Tags: python, naivebayes

I have the following values:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
model = GaussianNB()

d = {'Pos': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'Neg': [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1], 'Res': ['win','win','win','win','draw','loss','loss','loss','loss','loss',]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I then try and implement the following simple Naive Bayes classifcation

```
train, test = train_test_split(df,test_size=0.2) 
train_data = (train.Pos.values, train.Neg.values) 
train_target = train.Res.values 
model.fit(train_data, train_target)
```

however i keep getting the following error :

```
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 8]
```

I have experimented around, and it seems like rather than reading the values of both arrays, it is reads how many arrays (train.Pos.values, train.Neg.Values); which is potentially causing the issue.

Why is this the case? and how would i alter my code to fix this?

Comment: I belive `pd.Series.values()` returns unique values only, so in your 'Res' column, it's only returning 'win' and 'loss'.  I don't know what order exactly. Take this as the explanation that Evert's answer should have provided.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
train, test = train_test_split(df,test_size=0.2)
train_data = train[['Pos', 'Neg']]
train_target = train['Res']
```

Comment: @JoePearson I think you typed with single brackets... you want `[[...]]`, not `[...]`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a tuple of numpy arrays from the dataframe.  You want a single 2D array from the two columns.

```
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)
train_data = train.values[:, :2] 
train_target = train.Res.values
```